# How to concatenate the multiple column,when anyone of the column is having null value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement that I have to concatenate all the fields, and if any field is null then I have to give space.

For example:

```sql
-- If col1 value is not null
SELECT (YEAR||col1||(col2)) FROM table 
-- output: 202112abc

-- If col1 value is null
SELECT (YEAR||col1||(col2)) FROM table
-- output : 2021  abc
```

Can anyone please help me how we can do that, I tried multiple ways but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` to remove nulls or empty strings:

```
select (YEAR||case when col1 is null or col1 = '' then ' ' else col1 end||col2) from table
```

Comment: I tried but its not working ,getting output as 2021abc,but I need output as 2021  abc

Comment: SELECT Id||Name||number FROM NAMES;

o/p:

1Tom3
2Lucy4
35
4Jane6
5Robert7

SELECT Id||coalesce(Name,'')||number FROM NAMES;

o/p:

1Tom3
2Lucy4
35
4Jane6
5Robert7

Here for ID field ,name value is blank ,and I want the output like 3   5

Comment: please let me know ,If you need any more details.

Comment: I tried with giving space also between these 2 quotation marks,but still its not working as expected

SELECT Id||coalesce(Name,'  ')||number FROM NAMES;

o/p:

1Tom3
2Lucy4
35
4Jane6
5Robert7

Comment: maybe you have empty string instead of null. See edited answer which takes care of both.